# Cant revert back to ubuntu from lubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, lubuntu

So this was my first time doing a dual boot in my computer and i successfully did install ubuntu. However, in ubuntu i curiously downloaded lubuntu (since someone said that it was faster since lubuntu was feeling a bit slow) and unfortunately, I liked the layout of ubuntu at the end and got used to it. However, after rebooting it doesn't even let me choose the option of whether to start as ubuntu or lubuntu and it automatically starts as lubuntu which i hate T_T

I didn't put a login screen since it's my own computer and would like to know if there's a way to change back to ubuntu. Please! if you could explain step by step i'd be indefinitely graceful since I'm not a pro programmer or pro at ubuntu yet!

Thank you!

Comment: Can you check this links

- http://askubuntu.com/questions/416825/how-to-quick-switch-between-desktop-environments-in-the-running-desktop-session

- http://www.howtogeek.com/193129/how-to-install-and-use-another-desktop-environment-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove all the below packages and then need to install the ubuntu again,

sudo apt-get remove abiword abiword-common abiword-plugin-grammar abiword-plugin-mathview ace-of-penguins audacious audacious-plugins chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg elementary-icon-theme esound-common galculator gdebi gdebi-core giblib1 gnome-icon-theme-full gnome-mplayer gnome-system-tools gnome-time-admin gnumeric gnumeric-common gnumeric-doc gpicview gtk2-engines-pixbuf guvcview hardinfo indicator-status-provider-pidgin leafpad libabiword-3.0 libaiksaurus-1.2-0c2a libaiksaurus-1.2-data libaiksaurusgtk-1.2-0c2a libaudclient2 libaudcore1 libaudiofile1 libavcodec53 libavformat53 libavutil51 libbinio1ldbl libcddb2 libcompfaceg1 libcue1 libdca0 libdirectfb-1.2-9 libdiscid0 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libenca0 libencode-locale-perl libept1.4.12 libesd0 libexo-1-0 libexo-common libfaad2 libfile-listing-perl libfluidsynth1 libfm-data libfm-gtk-data libfm-gtk3 libfm3 libfont-afm-perl libgdome2-0 libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libglade2-0 libgoffice-0.8-8 libgoffice-0.8-8-common libgringotts2 libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgsm1 libgtkmathview0c2a libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libid3tag0 libimlib2 libio-socket-ssl-perl libjpeg-progs liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailtools-perl libmcrypt4 libmcs1 libmenu-cache3 libmms0 libmowgli2 libmusicbrainz3-6 libnet-dbus-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libobrender29 libobt2 libonig2 liboobs-1-5 libopenal1 libopts25 libots0 libpisock9 libpolkit-gtk-1-0 libpostproc52 libresid-builder0c2a libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsidplay2 libsvga1 libswscale2 libtar0 libtie-ixhash-perl libtimedate-perl libts-0.0-0 libuniconf4.6 liburi-perl libva1 libvdpau1 libvpx1 libwebcam0 libwv-1.2-4 libwvstreams4.6-base libwvstreams4.6-extras libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util4 libxfcegui4-4 libxfconf-0-2 libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpath-perl libxss1 libxvidcore4 link-grammar-dictionaries-en lm-sensors lubuntu-artwork lubuntu-core lubuntu-default-settings lubuntu-desktop lubuntu-icon-theme lxappearance lxappearance-obconf lxde-common lxde-core lxdm lxinput lxkeymap lxlauncher lxmenu-data lxpanel lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin lxrandr lxsession lxsession-edit lxshortcut lxtask lxterminal mplayer mtpaint ntp obconf openbox openbox-themes osmo pcmanfm pidgin pidgin-data pidgin-libnotify pidgin-microblog plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-lubuntu-text scrot sylpheed sylpheed-doc sylpheed-i18n sylpheed-plugins synaptic system-tools-backends transmission tsconf ttf-lyx uvcdynctrl uvcdynctrl-data wvdial xfburn xfce-keyboard-shortcuts xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-data xfconf xfonts-100dpi xpad xscreensaver xscreensaver-data

After this try installing the ubuntu,

sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Why in the world would you need to remove all those? Some of those are essential packages!